# influx schema type validations

Tags: influxdb

I am using influx db and I want to enforce some kind of schema validation.

I had a problem that influx had learned a filed using the wrong type due to a developer mistake. As a result, once we sent the right type, influx wouldn't persist it because it recognised the field of another type.

Can I force field types such as String, Integer and Double?

I use Java

Regards,
Ido

Comment: I don't think there is a way to limit inserted data types on database level. Essentially, InfluxDB is built around the idea that database schema is automatically defined on the first insertion and later database enforces this schema. Although, it holds for a single shard only. Datatypes may be different across shards - that gives you an opportunity to fix mistakes like this, without dropping a full series.

Comment: I've implemented that in software. Just a thin layer that I use when interacting with the DB. This was partially necessitated also because for some reason inserting a decimal value with only zeros after the decimal point such as "13.00" was interpreted as an Integer. Working with python and not sure where exactly it fails (from the http request to influxdb) but I also didn't care and just went with explicit typecasts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we have waited so long to see this feature finally in the newer release.

Starting from InfluxDB v2.4, we could create a bucket (new name for database in InfluxDB v2.X ) with an explicit schema. That is,

1. Create a bucket with an explicit schema (see more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.4/reference/cli/influx/bucket/create/#create-a-bucket-with-an-explicit-schema))

   ```
   influx bucket create \
      --name my_schema_bucket \
      --schema-type explicit
   ```
2. Adding measurement schemas to your bucket (see more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.4/reference/cli/influx/bucket-schema/create/#create-a-schema-using-the-influx-cli))

   ```
   influx bucket-schema create \
     --bucket my_schema_bucket \
     --name temperature \
     --columns-file columns.csv
   ```

where that column.csv is similar to DDL:

```
{"name": "time", "type": "timestamp"}
{"name": "alert", "type": "field", "dataType": "string"}
{"name": "cdi", "type": "field", "dataType": "float"}
```

You could refer to [this blog](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/new-bucket-schema-option-protect-from-unwanted-schema-changes/) as well.